# What Marvel movies have a lead actor's spouse/significant other as a side role in the same movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-love-and-thunder

In *Thor: Love and Thunder*, when describing Thor's love life, Korg explains how Thor fell in love with a "wolf woman", among others. The "wolf woman" was played by Elsa Pataky, Chris Hemsworth's wife. Has there ever been other instances of this in other Marvel movies, specifically where a lead actor's spouse or significant other has played another role in the movie? Any Marvel-produced movie or show, MCU or not, is acceptable.

*Note: I'd not accept the Tom Holland* Spider-Man *movies in the case of Tom Holland and Zendaya, who became a couple **after*** Spider-Man: Homecoming *was released.*

Comment: Mrs Hemsworth was also an extra in Ragnarok: https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Elsa_Pataky

Comment: Robert Downey Jr. and Marisa Tomei dated in the 1990s. I think they broke up because he was a massive cokehead. KIrsten Dunst dated at least two different Spider-Men

Comment: Zoe Saldana (Gamora) and Bradley Cooper (voice of Rocket) were engaged (but broke it off) a couple of years before they starred in Guardians of the Galaxy